# File execution with dot space versus dot slash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, operators, ksh

I am attempting to work with an existing library of code but have encountered an issue.  In short, I execute a shell script (let's call this one `A`) whose **first act** is to call another script (`B`).  Script `B` is in my current directory (a requirement of the program I'm using).  The software's manual makes reference to `bash`, however comments in `A` suggest it was developed in `ksh`.  I've been operating in `bash` so far.

Inside `A`, the line to execute `B` is simply:

```
. B
```

It uses the "dot space" syntax to call the program.  It doesn't do anything unusual like `sudo`.

When I call `A` without dot space syntax, i.e.:

```
./A
```

it always errors saying it cannot find the file `B`.  I added `pwd`, `ls`, `whoami`, `echo $SHELL`, and `echo $PATH` lines to `A` to debug and confirmed that `B` is in fact right there, the script is running with the same `$SHELL` as I am at the command prompt, the script is the same user as I am, and the script has the same search path `$PATH` as I do.  I also verified if I do:

```
. B
```

at the command line, it works just fine.  But, if I change the syntax inside `A` to:

```
./B
```

instead, then `A` executes successfully.

Similarly, if I execute `A` with dot space syntax, then both `. B` and `./B` work.

**Summarizing**:
`./A` only works if `A` contains `./B` syntax.
`. A` works for `A` with either `./B` or `. B` syntax.

I understand that using dot space (i.e. `. A`) syntax executes without forking to a subshell, but I don't see how this could result in the behavior I'm observing given that the file is clearly right there.  Is there something I'm missing about the nuances of syntax or parent/child process workspaces?  Magic?

**UPDATE1**:  Added info indicating that the script may have been developed in `ksh`, while I'm using `bash`.
**UPDATE2**:  Added checking to verify `$PATH` is the same.

**UPDATE3**:  The script says it was written for `ksh`, but it is running in `bash`.  In response to Kenster's answer, I found that running `bash -posix` then `. B` fails at the command line.  That indicates that the difference in environments between the command line and the script is that the latter is running `bash` in a POSIX-compliant mode, whereas the command line is not.  Looking a little closer, I see this in the `bash` `man` page:

> When invoked as sh, bash enters posix  mode  after  the  startup files are read.

The `shebang` for `A` is indeed `#!/bin/sh`.

In summary, when I run `A` without dot space syntax, it's forking to its own subshell, which is in POSIX-compliant mode because the `shebang` is `#!/bin/sh` (instead of, e.g., `#!/bin/bash`.  This is the critical difference between the command line and script runtime environments that leads to `A` being unable to find `B`.

Comment: Is `B` executable? `. B` doesn't technically `execute` `B`, it `sources` it. If one of them is `ksh`, try using `ksh yourscript`

Comment: Yes, `B` is executable.  I'm not clear on the difference between the two, will read now.

Comment: Never mind, I see `source` is the term (and a command) for running something in the same shell.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Let's start with how the command path works and when it's used. When you run a command like:

```
ls /tmp
```

The `ls` here doesn't contain a / character, so the shell searches the directories in your command path (the value of the PATH environment variable) for a file named `ls`. If it finds one, it executes that file. In the case of `ls`, it's usually in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, and both of those directories are typically in your path.

When you issue a command with a / in the command word:

```
/bin/ls /tmp
```

The shell doesn't search the command path. It looks specifically for the file `/bin/ls` and executes that.

Running `./A` is an example of running a command with a / in its name. The shell doesn't search the command path; it looks specifically for the file named `./A` and executes that. "." is shorthand for your current working directory, so `./A` refers to a file that ought to be in your current working directory. If the file exists, it's run like any other command. For example:

```
cd /bin
./ls
```

would work to run `/bin/ls`.

Running `. A` is an example of *sourcing* a file. The file being sourced must be a text file containing shell commands. It is executed by the current shell, without starting a new process. The file to be sourced is found in the same way that commands are found. If the name of the file contains a /, then the shell reads the specific file that you named. If the name of the file doesn't contain a /, then the shell looks for it in the command path.

```
. A        # Looks for A using the command path, so might source /bin/A for example
. ./A      # Specifically sources ./A
```

So, your script tries to execute `. B` and fails claiming that `B` doesn't exist, even though there's a file named `B` right there in your current directory. As discussed above, the shell would have searched your command path for `B` because `B` didn't contain any / characters. When searching for a command, the shell doesn't automatically search the current directory. It only searches the current directory if that directory is part of the command path.

In short, `. B` is probably failing because you don't have "." (current directory) in your command path, and the script which is trying to source `B` is assuming that "." is part of your path.  In my opinion, this is a bug in the script. Lots of people run without "." in their path, and the script shouldn't depend on that.

*Edit:*

You say the script uses `ksh`, while you are using `bash`. Ksh follows the POSIX standard--actually, KSH was the basis for the POSIX standard--and always searches the command path as I described.  Bash has a flag called "POSIX mode" which controls how strictly it follows the POSIX standard. When not in POSIX mode--which is how people generally use it--bash will check the current directory for the file to be sourced if it doesn't find the file in the command path.

If you were to run `bash -posix` and run `. B` within that bash instance, you should find that it won't work.

Comment: You're right about the current directory not being in `$PATH`.  I had thought about this, but then why does `. B` work at the command line?  I tried `echo $PATH` and it's the same in both the script and my.  That's the real core of my question, why does the script fail where the command line succeeds if it looks like everything (shell, environmental variables, etc.) is the same?

Comment: Yep, fails with `bash -posix`.  I went back and figured out why the script was running with POSIX-compliant mode and added a full explanation to the original question (wouldn't fit here).

Comment: Maybe also explain that sourcing a file in the current process means the sourced file can manipulate your environment. So if you run `. B` and `B` does `foo=bar` then this variable will be set when `B` finishes, until the current script or interactive shell exits, whereas `./A` cannot change your variables (a subprocess cannot change its parent).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is great, and the question is a good one, with excellent research and nuanced differences in `ksh` vs `bash` and `#!/bin/sh` vs `#!/bin/bash`. I had a different error re the question title "File execution with dot space versus dot slash", so I'm posting here in case it helps other people...

When I tried

`./cmdFile.cmd`

The shell could find the file, but I got a **permissions error**:

> bash: ./cmdFile.cmd: Permission denied

When I tried:

`. cmdFile.cmd` (or `. ./cmdFile.cmd`)

It ran the cmd as expected, no permissions error.

So I'm only posting my answer in case you're facing permissions issues. (instead of "file could not be found")... (Maybe I should post a different question?)

As the original question says, and the expected answer says, the difference in syntax is whether a new subshell (`./cmdFile.cmd`) vs executing in the current shell when "sourcing" with dot-space syntax: (`. cmdFile.cmd`).

In other words, [as said here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=descriptions-dot-run-shell-file-in-current-environment), the "sourcing" command (dot-space syntax) is different:

> **. (dot)** runs a shell script in the current environment and then returns. Normally, the shell runs a command file in a child shell so that changes to the environment by such commands as **cd**, **set**, and **trap** are local to the command file. The **. (dot)** command circumvents this feature.

... and this might affect your permissions.

In my case I user the [`sudo` (superuser-do) command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)  and the [`su` (substitute-user) command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix)) like this: `sudo su {user-with-permissions}` before I try to run any `cmd` file, maybe this is also related...